# Java config for Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, architecture

As far as I know, there are two ways to configure JPA / Hibernate:

- XML based configuration through something like hibernate.cfg.xml. I don't like his approach because, well, XML ...
- Through annotations in the entity object. Much better than the XML config, but it couples my entities to JPA.

As I am currently investigating an architecture where the domain model does not know anything about the database (The 'Onion' architecture), I am looking for is a way to specify the mappings without changing my entities.

Of course I *could* create separate mapping classes, e.g. if I have a Customer domain object, create a JPA-annotated CustomerEntity and let the repository translate from one to another. But this approach doesn't feel quite right because the Customer and CustomerEntity will essentially be the same.

So it seems like I have to resort to Hibernate XML configuration, but as mentioned before, I don't like that approach.
Spring has a nice way of configuration: Java-based configuration. I was wondering if there is something similar for Hibernate/JPA configuration, and if not, why not?

My apologies if none of the above makes sense, but any help is welcome, even if it doesn't answer my question :-)

Comment: Aren't annotations effectively Java?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I meant. My purpose is to separate the JPA mapping from the domain entities. When using annotations, that is not the case.

Comment: Yea, but I don't know how you would go about describing Entities any simpler than by using annotations. If you separate them you just make code that's difficult to read, use, and maintain.

Comment: It's about separation of concerns. Your core domain model should not need to know anything about the way it is stored. JPA mapping is a separate concern, and should therefore not be part of the domain model. At least that's the theory of the "Onion Architecture". But as I said, I just started experimenting with this so I don't know either :-)

Comment: Someone here is working on some sort of utility for hibernate package scanning: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3405171/v-ladynev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly there is somethinig called [Fluent NHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) for C#, which does exactly what I was looking for.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no "Fluent Hibernate" for Java.

There is a [fluent-hibernate](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate) project on GitHub, but that one seems to be about fluently writing HQL-queries, not about mapping configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of an `Onion Theory` of Java EE design. I did hear of `The Onion`, but that's a satirical newsletter (if that :-). Separation of concerns in Java EE I typically expressed as a MVC, or Model View Controller architecture. Your JSP or JSF pages will be your view, your `@ManagedBean` controllers will be your controllers, and your model will hold your Entities.

The model, which is where the JPA will be, can usually be further separated into a `Service Layer`, a `Persistence Layer` and EIS (Enterprise Information System) or Database tier. The Service tier will hold your EJBs, annotated with `Stateless`, `Statefull` or `Singleton`, and will encapsulate the business logic for the application. The `Persistence Layer` will have @Entity annotated objects that are stored by the Database.

Java EE defines these layers with JSR's, with numbers of some sort. For example, the Java Persistence API (JPA) is JSR-220. Tests are developed against these JSR's and if a vendor meets these tests then their product can be (More or less) swapped out for another vender's version.

Comment: Ah, the classic layered architecture. It has it's own problems. As I mentioned, I am investigating a different kind of architecture called "Onion architecture". If you don't know what it is, do a google search. It's easy to find. The point is that the JPA will NOT be in the model. Yes, with JPA you can swap out Oracle and swap in MSSQL, but what if you wanted to change to Neo4j? Or cloud storage? No way to do that with JPA-annotated entites.